# What is $HOME/.lvm

Tags: linux, shell, lvm

What is `$HOME/.lvm` (`lvm history`) and where we use it in [LVM](http://www.datadisk.co.uk/html_docs/redhat/rh_lvm.htm)?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a part of [GNU Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline): it keeps track of history for the interactive `lvm` command just like bash_history does for bash. See the [lvm(8) manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lvm.8.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

The Logical Volume Manager (LVM) can be used either directly e.g.:

```
# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  [..]

# vgscan
  Found volume group "data" using metadata type lvm2
```

or interactively e.g.:

```
# lvm
lvm> lvdisplay 
  --- Logical volume ---
  [...]
   
lvm> vgscan
  Found volume group "data" using metadata type lvm2
```

When used interactively the command history is kept in `~/.lvm_history`:

```
# cat ~/.lvm_history 
lvdisplay 
vgscan
```

Similar to the bash history file(`~/.bash_history`):

```
# cat ~/.bash_history 
lvscan
pvscan
```